# Dockerize Rails project with postgres and redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, redis

Am new to RoR and I want to dockerize a Rails app with Redis and Postgres running in 3 different containers.

I now have a simple rails project running inside a container

How would I configure the RoR project to do the following:

1. How to connect Rails with Postgres?
2. How to setup Redis with Rails as a simple in-memory data store and access it?

Thanks :)

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  rails: 
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  postgres:
    image: postgres
  redis:
    image: redis
```

**EDIT:**

Changed sqlite db to postgres

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? In development you should probably try docker-compose if you haven't already (if you have, post your docker-compose.yml so far). Also since SQLite is not an actual server, this particular aspect of your docker stack would probably be a volume mount rather than a container.

Comment: I didn't know that Sqlite is not an actual server. Is it then possible to use postgres instead of sqlite here?

Comment: sqlite is direct-to-file database, and is mostly used as an embedded database in other apps (non web). I also edited your question subject to say postgres instead of sqlite, and provided an answer below that is hopefully helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has multiple aspects:

1. docker - usage and networking
2. docker compose usage
3. rails - database configuration
4. redis use in a rails environment

If you don't yet feel comfortable with all of them, I recommend you try to eliminate some of the noise, and first make sure you attack each topic separately, and ask questions that are more isolated to a given aspect - it will make it easier for us to help.

Nevertheless, to answer the docker (-compose) part of your question, you are missing some elements in your configuration. This example should get you on the right track I hope:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
volumes: 
  pgdata:

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/pgdata
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypass
      - POSTGRES_USER=rails
      - PGDATA=/pgdata

  redis:
    image: redis

  web:
    image: you/your_app
    build: .
    command: bin/rails server
    depends_on: [db, redis]
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
    volumes: 
      - $PWD:/app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://rails:mypass@db/your_db_name
      REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379
```

If you look at your rails folder, in the `config/database.yml` file, you should see that `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is used to tell Rails where its Postgres database is.

As soon as you are able to make your rails app run locally (without docker), it should be a straight forward switch to docker-land.

**Redis**

Redis has many uses in Rails.
Assuming you are simply looking to use redis as a key value store, this is quite simple.

A. Add the `redis` gem to your Gemfile.

B. Create an initializer, for example in `config/initializers/redis.rb` and put this in it:

```rb
# This automatically reads the REDIS_URL from the environment
$redis ||= Redis.new
```

C. Anywhere else in your code, you can use it like this:

```rb
$redis.ping
$redis.set "some-key", "some-value"
$redis.get "some-key"
```

- For other uses, you may want to consider the [redis-rails gem](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails)
- For more information about the use of the `redis` gem, see its [readme](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb)

Comment: Thanks mate that's all I needed for postgres. But how to connect redis with database.yml file?

Comment: Added some redis hints. If you get stuck with it, I suggest a separate question with the code snippets of what you have tried and having troubles with.